# Coloring the character using charAt JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may seem to be a silly question and I am sorry if it is.

I am in need to color a character present inside a string and to locate this character I am using JavaScripts `string.charAt()` from a editable div,this is needed to highlight the matching braces in the string
e.g string

```
abcdef{gh13435}
```

In above mentioned string if the cursor's location is at the opening brace then I will assign some color to it and its closing piece in order to highlight them.

I can locate the character using charAt function but after that is there a way of assigning the color to the character **without wrapping it inside a HTML tag(span,font or any other)** like accessing its style property or something else?
Might be Im missing some basics here.
.
I searched it a lot but didn't found anything relevant.

Help/directions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Agree with Greg, just follow how HTML is really done. Rest is cool!!

Comment: cant  string.charAt be converted to some object pointing to the character?no way like that?

Comment: If you don't have to wrap it, wrap all the other sibling text nodes instead and apply color to the parent of it, other sibling text nodes will be styled by applying color to their wrappers (to override the color of the parent). It's a much longer way to go.

Comment: How HTML thinks of the data written between the tags is: TEXT. that may be referred as a single object. The most you can do is: Pull that char from string out(on the fly) > wrap it into another object > and then play with this new object.(That's exactly like wrapping it into a div / span).

Comment: How does they have this on the online code editors?What is the approach they use?

Comment: on-the-fly conversion of the html representation of parts of the text currently visible. basically it's the same that you plan albeit with a different representation for coloring glyphs ( ie. html/css wrapper instead of an attribute of an abstract glyph datatype).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you'll definitely have to wrap it inside another tag like span or font. That's how html works.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg said, the color is not an attribute of the characters you print.

You might implement your design by displaying 2 divs with suitable background color beneath the matching characters you wish to highlight.

however this would require to properly identify the screen position of the respective characters, to add positioning code, probably setting up 2 divs for your editing pane (one on top holding your text with transparent background, one at the bottom with the desired background color of your editing pane) which would sandwich the highlighting divs, definitely setting up some keypress handlers (or additions to their code, respectively), and most liekly some other gadgets that elude my mind right now.

honestly, i wouldn't consider this being worth the trouble (assuming it was a viable approach at all).

keep to Greg's answer, that's the sensible way to go.